# Ubuntu 16.04 Unity does not load - icons and not displayed

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I am running VirtualBox Version 5.0.22 with Ubuntu 16.04.
I performed an update today and then got into the problem that has happened 
to so many others:

Icons&menys dissapeared.

There is a thread for this discussed here:

[Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

But, I believe I have tried everything discussed in that thread,
like:

sudo service lightdm stop
rm ~/.config/dconf/user
sudo service lightdm start

and:

sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity

and:

using unity-tweak-tool.

and:

and enable Unity using ccsm,

and

export DISPLAY=:0
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity

and other suggestions presented:

but nothing seem to works.

Anyone else who have run into this?

Someone who have a suggestion not already discussed or have a proposal of a solution already presented, that needs some tweaking for 16.04 ?

Comment: Is this really a duplicate if the 10 most upvoted answers in the "duplicate" don't work? Sure, the symptoms are the same, but the solution is not.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and none of the solutions worked. Until I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/827296/532949) which was posted just 5 hours ago.

Delete your .cache folder in your home directory and reboot. It also deletes your settings and locked launch bar icons but that is no big deal.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I reinstalled the VM since it was a kinda new Image, if it happends again, I will remove the .cache folder. Thanks.