# Unity launch bar and menu bar won't come up on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, launcher

I have an old 32-bit netbook and have been running Ubuntu since 2012. I currently run Ubuntu 16.04 LTR and have run update manager consistently. When I logged in today, my wallpaper came up but without the launch bar and without the top menu bar. I have tried everything I know of, including some of the older suggestions on this site. Despite being a long-time Ubuntu user, I am not code-savvy. I use the Unity interface for everything. Can you help?

Comment: You could try to [restart Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/495997/how-to-properly-restart-unity), or [reset Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration), whichever works best.

Comment: I think one of the other ideas will help better, but maybe try to click the escape key.  My 19.04 opens up in full screen mode for some strange reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's been a few posts lately of launcher disappearing. Most likely everyone suffered from the same update which introduced a bug. When you boot your computer choose from the grub menu "Advanced options for Ubuntu". From the submenu select the next oldest kernel version that works.

Other than that check these Q&As:

- [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)
- [Ubuntu 16.04 - Unity doesn't load - no Launcher or Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962497/ubuntu-16-04-unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-or-dash-appears)
- [No launcher and menu bar on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811552/no-launcher-and-menu-bar-on-ubuntu-16-04)
- [Ubuntu Menu and Launcher not showing after 2/16/2018 update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007026/ubuntu-menu-and-launcher-not-showing-after-2-16-2018-update)
- [Ubuntu 16.04 Unity does not load - icons and not displayed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/810091/ubuntu-16-04-unity-does-not-load-icons-and-not-displayed)

---

#### Edit: July 15, 2019

After answer was accepted a comment was made how system worked in recovery mode. If that's the case try the solution in this answer:

- [Ubuntu Menu and Launcher not showing after 2/16/2018 update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007026/ubuntu-menu-and-launcher-not-showing-after-2-16-2018-update)

Open a terminal and use:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/*
sudo reboot
```

When rebooting select the most recent kernel rather than the older recovery option.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "grub menu". When I boot the computer, I briefly see: <F9> Change Boot Device Order and <F10)> BIOS Setup Options.

Comment: @ChrisM. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time

Comment: Got it! Many thanks. Of note, the buggy kernel was 4.4.0.154. In the grub menu, it showed three choices of my next oldest version: 4.4.0.151, 4.4.0.151 (upstart), and 4.4.0.151 (recovery mode). At first, I chose 4.4.0.151 but it did not bring up the launcher. Next I chose 4.4.0.151 (recovery mode) and it did bring up the launcher and menu bar. Thanks again!

Comment: Booting in recovery mode is not an ideal method long term. It is probably due to broken advanced graphics that regular booting is broken. That problem should be fixed.

Comment: @ChrisM. I've revised the answer. Please try out the edit and let me know if you can boot back into the regular kernel. I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I entered the code above and then chose 4.4.0.151 (not 4.4.0.154, if that's what you meant by the most recent kernel) from the grub menu, and the launcher came up! I checked for system updates and there are currently none. Hopefully I will be able to update to future versions of the kernel that are not buggy. I appreciate you giving this your attention.

Comment: The most recent would be too of main menu without going into submenu at all.